# Jenkins Plugin Development Gradle Build

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins, build.gradle

Building a Jenkins Plugin that creates a `SimpleBuildStep`.

It works with `maven hpi:run` but I need to switch it to `gradle`

My problem is that when I run `gradle server` I can see my custom plugin is installed but it is not in the build step.

I thought it was my versioning and I changed it several times. I'm wondering if my configuration is wrong.

I have a `work` directory that shows up and my plugin is shown in `work/plugins/` with a  `.hpi` and a `.hpl` file but it still doesn't work. It only works in maven it also doesn't show when I do a docker instance of jenkins (which is always at jenkins version 2)

I'm still assuming it is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
  id "org.jenkins-ci.jpi" version "0.16.0"
}

jenkinsPlugin {
    coreVersion = "2.0"                                               // Version of Jenkins core this plugin depends on.
    displayName = "Test Jenkins Plugin"                // Human-readable name of plugin.
    url = "http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SomePluginPage"   // URL for plugin on Jenkins wiki or elsewhere.
    shortName = "jetson"                                           // Plugin ID, defaults to the project name without trailing '-plugin'
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.main', name: 'ui-samples-plugin', version: '1.424.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

EDIT: Have it working. I can actually use my plugin in my instance now.

Changes:

After examining the `hpl` file and reading it. I realized that my Jenkins plugin *wasn't even registering my classes*. I realized cause my `build.gradle` was in a folder in the root project. So obviously I moved `build.gradle` into the root.

From there I noticed it actually built those classes. Still couldn't get my plugin to actually show up as a build step even though it showed up under installed (**same old problem**). I took another `build.gradle` from a different plugin and edited for my own use. It works, however I have no idea why.

*I also had to add a missing dependency I was having, now that it was actually building my project.

new `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // The plugin is currently only available via the Jenkins
        // Maven repository, but has dependencies in Maven Central.
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jenkins-ci.tools:gradle-jpi-plugin:0.14.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.jenkins-ci.jpi'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/"
  }
}

group = 'workday'
version = '0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'Test AS A Service Plugin'

jenkinsPlugin {
    // version of Jenkins core this plugin depends on, must be 1.420 or later
    coreVersion = '1.654'

    // ID of the plugin, defaults to the project name without trailing '-plugin'
    shortName = 'jetson'

    // human-readable name of plugin
    displayName = 'Jetson Test Plugin'


    // use the plugin class loader before the core class loader, defaults to false
    pluginFirstClassLoader = true

    // optional list of package prefixes that your plugin doesn't want to see from core
    maskClasses = 'groovy.grape org.apache.commons.codec'

    // optional version number from which this plugin release is configuration-compatible
    compatibleSinceVersion = '1.1.0'


    // enable injection of additional tests for checking the syntax of Jelly and other things
    disabledTestInjection = false

    // the output directory for the localizer task relative to the project root, defaults to the value shown
    localizerOutputDir = "${project.buildDir}/generated-src/localizer"


    // plugin file extension, either 'jpi' or 'hpi', defaults to 'hpi'
    fileExtension = 'hpi'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.main', name: 'ui-samples-plugin', version: '1.424.2'
       compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.14'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

I suspect it actually has to do with the new `buildscripts` blocks for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set your group to

```
group = 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins'
```

and you can delete the

```
apply plugin 'java'
```

as this is done internally (I think)

I'm not sure you need to include the ui-samples-plugin either but if you do it needs to be something like

```
dependencies {
    jenkinsPlugins( group:   'org.jenkins-ci.main', 
                    name:    'ui-samples-plugin', 
                    version: '1.424.2', 
                    ext:     'jar')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

(untested)

Try its [wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+JPI+Plugin) for more info

Comment: wait group in my `jenkinsPlugin` block? I thought that block was for my own information about the plugin like my groups and etc?

Comment: also in the wiki page you sent me it even says to do all my plugin dependencies as I did. where did you get your convention of adding plugins?

Comment: I updated my answer. The dependencies are discussed here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html  You can probably not change the group if you weren't going to release the plugin

Comment: yeah its an internal plugin, wouldn't be of any use to other developers. So I see how you did the dependencies now. I actually did it a different way but not so sure why it worked. Though in truth one thing was I moved the build.gradle into the root of the project which I should've been done! I'll post my new file and changes. Please help me figure out the differences lol.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is its `jenkinsPlugins` rather than `compile` for the plugin dependency